# Converting an int array list to an int array

Tags: arrays, arraylist, int, java.util.scanner

EDIT:
I am trying to add elements read from a txt document line by line into an array list then convert that array list into an array. Although I am getting errors with my code. It doesnt like the int[] a = lines.toArray(new int[lines.size()]);.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class insertionSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> lines = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    File file = new File("10_Random.txt");

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        //int line = null;

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            lines.add(i);
            //System.out.println(i);
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int[] a = lines.toArray(new int[lines.size()]);
}
}
```

Edit2: Thanks chaitanya10! all fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int line= null; is wrong,
```

"null is a special literal that can be of any object reference type".you cant assign `null` to `primitive variables` in java like (int, byte, float...). `null can only be assigned to objects . remember that`null`is the default vale for`objects` when you don't initialize them.

if you wanna access int as an object use `Integer`.

```
Integer line= null;//nowthis would compile
```

and to convert an list onto array do this.

List.toArray(T[] t) method returns an Object. 
do like below.

```
Integer[] array = lines.toArray(new Integer[lines.size()])
```

and also your List accepts int[] array and you are tryig to add an int into the list .

change your List declaration like this

```
List<Integer> lines = new ArrayLis<Integer>();
```

To print the elements in the array you have to iterate over it

```
    for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
    system.out.println(a[i])
}
```

you seem to be a beginner in java. strongly recommend you to[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html)read about java basic

Comment: Wrote this "int[] a = lines.toArray(new int[lines.size()]);" and im getting an error message wanting met o remove the argument to change it to .toArray(). also It still doesnt like the lines.add(i);

Comment: Ok that fixed my lines.add problem now I need to fix this "int[] a = lines.toArray(new int[lines.size()]);" :-)

Comment: you are amazing my friend :-)

Comment: Oh! can you help me with something else? I tried printing the list out and I got "[Ljava.lang.Integer;@452c0b3f" as the output. I put "System.out.println(a);" under the Integer[] a..... stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Two main problems.

- You can't assign `null` to an `int`. `null` is a pointer value, and `int`s in Java are always handled by value, not by reference. Objects can be `null`, primitive values like `int` and `double` can't.
- The type declaration of your `ArrayList` is wrong. The way you're assigning it, *each element* of the list is expected to be an array of `int`s. I don't think that's really what you want - the each element is just one `int` value, so that the list *as a whole* is analogous to an array.

The second bullet is the reason behind your second and third errors, which I think you'd probably see if you read the error messages all the way through (it's a TypeMismatch error, right?). With your list parameterized to `int[]`, the `add` method is expecting everything that's added to be of the type `int[]`. But `line` is only an `int`. Similarly, the `toArray()` method returns an array of whatever type the list is parameterized with. Since you have a list of arrays, `toArray()` will return an *array of arrays*. Its return type in this case is `int[][]`, which can't be assigned to `int[] a` because the type doesn't match.

This should get your code to compile, but it doesn't get into the other issues of validation and whatnot that you have to worry about any time you have input... but for now I'm just going to assume that you've already vetted the input file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IntStream:

```
int[] arr = {15, 13, 7, 4, 1, 10, 0, 7, 7, 12, 15};
List<Integer> arrayList = IntStream.of(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(arrayList);
```